# React button component not disappearing unless clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

I have a sign out component that doesn't let me unselect any part of my app unless I click it itself. Using React Material UI

```
<MenuItem onClick={e => this.onSignOut(e)}>
  Sign Out
</MenuItem>
```

onSignOut functions

```
onSignOut() {
SignOut();
this.props.logoutUserFromReduxState();
{
  localStorage.clear();
  this.props.history.push('/auth/login');
}
}
```

Is there a way to unselect it if I don't click on it.

Comment: Ok, let me gotta this. that button is static, I mean it always has stayed open, right?? but, when you select another component, you can't unselect it until you click the sign out button, am I right??

Comment: I'm not very familiar with material-ui but still, can you show us the 'MenuItem'  component? Moreover you should make the onSignOut() as an arrow function if you're using 'this' reference of a class.

Comment: Can you show us some of the code around the `MenuItem` component? So that we can reproduce the issue ourselves?

Comment: @KenrySanchez yes that is correct!

Comment: @JulesDupont MenuItem is part of the Material-Ui library https://material-ui-next.com/api/menu-item/

Comment: @dankthreads Yes, I know `MenuItem` is from material-ui. I'm asking for how you're using that `MenuItem` in your app because I suspect the issue is a forgotten `onClose` prop on the surrounding `Menu` component.

Comment: Do you solve this issue??

Comment: Not yet @KenrySanchez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating to the latest version of Material-UI